# Accumulation points in C

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following set

$S = \{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{i}{m}: m,n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

I already got the accumulation points and proved that they are accumulation points of S
$S` = \{\frac{1}{n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \} \cup \{\frac{i}{m}: m \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$

However I don't know how to prove they are the only accumulation points of S in $R^2$. I am learning topology by myself so some guidance would be nice. I am confused since since we have to consider $R^2 - S`$ and have to prove it for all those points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show that nobody else is an accumulation point. We do **one** case in detail.

Let  $x=a+bi$, where $a\gt 0$, and $a\ne \frac{1}{m}$ for any natural number $m$. We will show that $x$ is not an accumulation point of $S$.

Let $U$ be the set of natural numbers $m$ such that $\frac{a}{2}\le \frac{1}{m}\lt \frac{3a}{2}$.  The set $U$ is finite, so as $m$ ranges over $U$, $\left|\frac{1}{m}-a\right|$ has a smallest value $u$. Let $w=\min(u,a/2)$. Then for every complex number $s$ of the form $s=\frac{1}{m}+\frac{i}{n}$, we have $|a+bi-s|\ge w$, which implies $a+bi$ is not an accumulation point of $S$.

We have dealt with the case $a\gt 0$ and not of the shape $\frac{1}{m}$. There are a few other cases to deal with. (One can deal with all cases in one blow, but how may only become clear after doing them separately.)